Translation message can not contain stringified json
I am new to nuxt.
I installed i18n to handle translations
i checked https://i18n.nuxtjs.org/docs/getting-started
my defineI18nConfig:
nuxt-app/i18n.config.ts
export default defineI18nConfig(() => ({
    legacy: false,
    locale: 'en',
    fallbackLocale: "en",
    escapeParameterHtml: false,
    warnHtmlMessage: false,
    messages: {
        en: {

            welcome: "hello dear human {\"key\": \"value\"}"

        },
        fr: {

            welcome: "hello dear human fr"

        }
    },
}))

pages/index.vue
<script setup>


const { locale, setLocale } = useI18n()
</script>
<template>
  <div>
    <div>
      <button class="btn ml-3" @click="setLocale('en')">en</button>
      <button class="btn ml-3" @click="setLocale('fr')">fr</button>
      <p>{{ $t('welcome') }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

Error:
Message compilation error: Invalid token in placeholder: '"key":'
1  |  hello dear human {"key": "value"}

My problem i have some json examples in my translations that i can not delete
i imported i18n in config,
modules: ["@nuxtjs/i18n"],

  i18n: {
    vueI18n: './i18n.config.ts'
  }

It is possible to have json in translates or not ?

Do you want to compile the result as hello dear human {"key": "value"} for users in HTML? or do you want to compile the result as hello dear human value?

You may use hello dear human {key} instead of hello dear human {\"key\": \"value\"}, also in the template {{ $t('welcome', {key: 'Tom'}) }}, see the vue-i18n interpolations

my translations contains a guide for some inputs and i have in translations stringyfied objects



const i18n = VueI18n.createI18n({
  locale: 'en',
  messages: {
    en: {
      hello: `hello world {'{'}"key": "value"{'}'}`
    }
  }
})

const app = Vue.createApp()

app.use(i18n)
app.mount('#app')
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-i18n@9"></script>

<div id="app">
  {{ $t('hello') }}
</div>



use {'@'} for the placeholder
see vue-i18n Literal interpolation
